# Context root of a springboot application war file in dev enviroment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a built a spring boot war file (WebApplication) using maven with the following config in application.properties. 
server.servlet.context-path=/app
When deploying the war in Tomcat manually in a dev environment, It is not reading the context path but rather using the name of the war file as the context path.

War file name : AgentApp.0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.

Actual url : http://dev.com/AgentApp.0.0.1.SNAPSHOT/index.html.

Expected url : http://dev.com/app/index.html.

P.S : This works fine in my local environment, when runnning from eclipse.(Not with embedded tomcat).

Comment: All the server properties are for the *EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION* (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). You're not using an embedded server, since you deploy your app in an external web server.

Comment: @JBNizet Right, How do I set the context path when deploying the app on an external tomcat server?

Comment: You read the documentation of Tomcat. Googling for "Tomcat context path" leads to the relevant pages. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Answer (score 0):

You can use the propertie spring.application.name in your application.properties.

```
spring.application.name=/app
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add the `<finalName>`  tag in the pom.xml. When the maven build is done the war/jar file will be the name of the finalName.